# load combox values after declare username with input

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

i'm biulding a very simple Windows form application connected to sql compact database with a simple 2 columns table name usersDBS, one column hold username and the other dataname. in panel 1 user declare himself and move to panel 2 where he need to pick a database to login to from a combox that hold all the datanames from the table where username equal the user that loged in. but how i load the values in the combox only after i get the username in panel 1? as i undarstend combox are loaded with the load of the form so do i need to reload the form or create a 2 forms application? im a sql server dba so im weak in vs undertanding. please explain to me the logic way. no code needed only explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing a "leave" event for that first text box. after you have done that I would recommend querying for what you need to and then setting the datasource of the combobox.

Comment: thank for the help. i didnt managed with the "leave" event. i end up useing 2 forms in my application so username is set in first form and used for loading combobox on form 2. if anyone have a better way to do it i will be happy to learn. thanks you Digit Plays